# Cannot open include file: '*Inst.inc' when build DirectXTK

Tags: directxtk

When built DirectXTK, VS2019 reported:

```
Cannot open include file: 'DebugEffect_VSDebugInst.inc': No such file or directory
Cannot open include file: 'NormalMapEffect_VSNormalPixelLightingTxInst.inc': No such file or directory
Cannot open include file: 'PBREffect_VSConstantInst.inc': No such file or directory
```

I pulled source code from https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK, opened DirectXTK_Desktop_2019_Win10.sln to build, and got this error.

Answer (score 1):

This would indicate a partial build of the shaders, meaning that some of the shader blob .inc files were successful but not all of them were built. It could be a path-depth issue depending on *where* you cloned the library.

Try opening a *x64 Native Tools Command Prompt*, then change to the `DirectXTK\Src\Shaders` directory. Then run `CompileShaders.cmd`. Look for any errors.

Then check the contents of `DirectXTK\Src\Shaders\Compiled`.